# graphite summarize function not working as expected

Tags: graphite

I am feeding data into a metric, let say it is "local.junk". What I send is just that metric, a 1 for the value and the timestamp

```
local.junk 1 1394724217
```

Where the timestamp changes of course.  I want to graph the total number of these instances over a period of time so I used

```
summarize(local.junk, "1min")
```

Then I went and made some data entries, I expected to see the number of requests that it received in each minute but it always just shows the line at 1. If I summarize over a longer period like 5 mins, It is showing me some random number... I tried 10 requests and I see the graph at like 4 or 5.  Am I loading the data wrong?  Or using the summarize function wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The method `summarize()` just sums up your data values so co-relate and verify that you indeed are sending correct values.

Also, to localize weather the function or data has issues, you can run it on `metricsReceived`:

```
summarize(carbon.agents.ip-10-0-0-1-a.metricsReceived,"1hour")
```

Which version of Grahite are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your [carbon aggregator settings](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html#aggregation-rules-conf). By default carbon aggregates data for every 10 seconds. Without adding any entry in aggregation-rules.conf, Graphite only saves last metric it receives in the 10second duration.

You are seeing above problem because of that behaviour. You need to add an entry for your metric in the aggregation-rules.conf with `sum` method like this

```
local.junk (10) = sum local.junk
```